# JQuery GET retrieves unwanted HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using a php cart class, and have added some jquery to update a div when users click to add products.

The problem I am having is that when a product is added the list of products is duplicated on the html page (screenshot) though it's not there in the source of it.

Default page:

[image]

---

And when any product is added this is the result:

[image]

---

As you can see the cart is updated but a duplicate set of products appear.

Here's the JQuery I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getItem(id)
{
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: 'index2.php',
 data: "action=add&id=" + id,
 success: function(data) {
      $('#info').html(data);
 }

 });

 }
 </script>
```

And the PHP with between the div with id info:

```
<div id="info">
<?php
if(!empty($items)){
    echo '
    <table style="border:2px solid #cc0000;width:400px">
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Item</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Price</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Quantity</strong></td>
        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>';

    $total = 0;
    foreach($items as $id=>$qty) {
        foreach($products as $product) {
            if($product['id'] == $id)
                break;
        }
        if(!isset($product['name']))
            continue;

        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $product['name'] . '</td>
            <td>$' . $product['price'] . '</td>
            <td>' . $qty . '</td>
            <td>$' . ($product['price'] * $qty) . '</td>
            <td><a href="?action=remove&id=' . $id . '">[x Remove]</a></td>
        </tr>';

        $total += $product['price'] * $qty;
    }

    echo '
    <tr>
        <td><a href="?action=empty">[Empty Cartt]</a></td>
        <td colspan="4" align="right"><strong>Grand Total: $' . $total . '</strong></td>
    </tr>
    </table>';
}
else{
    echo '<p style="color:#990000;">Your shopping cart is empty.</p>';
}
?>
</div>
```

I don't know what is causing this.

Any solutions would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the code for `index2.php`?

Comment: The html above is from index2. The script is in the same page.

Comment: So your ajax request returns the same data which is already in the page. What do you expect?

Comment: Just the cart part not the product table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're rendering a copy of the entire page inside of itself.  Note the repeated headers.

Solutions are to make sure that index2.php (or whatever endpoint is best) only includes the info template, OR that you're intentionally re-rendering the entire view (and should set the html of the parent container, not the inner one).

Comment: How can i just get that part? I thought only the #info div will only be retrieved?

Comment: If you only want the info template, you need an endpoint which only renders that template.  It looks like you're getting the entire page.  JQuery has no idea which part of the rendered page you want.  You could use an additional query to specify only the portion of the HTML that you want, but this only hides the fact that you're sending way more HTML than you need; it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: thank you for replying, any examples of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting the `#info` div inside another div with the same `id` everytime, Try to use **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** instead, to make sur taht you've just one div with the same id in the same time, like :

```
$('#info').replaceWith(data);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that, but replaceWith keeps adding more tables below. So didn't work